# Over heating issue with ubuntu in dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, radeon, overheating, amd-ryzen

These are the running processes after I used the `systemctl list-units --type=service --state=running` command

[image: img_running_process]

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on dual boot with windows 10.But, I don't know why but my laptop heats up when I use ubuntu even for simple tasks like youtube. It does not heat up if I use Windows.

My laptop is HP 245 G7.
Ryzen 3, 4GB RAM, 1TB HDD, Windows 10, Radeon Vega 6 Graphics(integrated).

I love ubuntu but this heating issue is very annoying.

Please help me fix it.

Comment: I think there are some services running that heat your laptop up. Can you show us "systemctl list-units --type=service --state=running"

Comment: @ThomasAichinger sir, i updated the question with the image, please help

Comment: I would try to disable these services one after each other. bluetooth, modemmanager, whoopsie, switchero See if one of these services is responsible.